# aggregating unique values in columns to single dataframe "cell"

Tags: r

Hello great and omnificent stackoverflow,

I have a data frame structured like so.

```
Person     Dilution      Analyte     Meta#1      Meta#2
john         1            Blank       3x          100
john         2            Blank       3x          100
john         1            mulv        3x          100
john         2            mulv        3x          100
john         1            gp41        3x          100
john         2            gp41        3x          100
kelly        20           blank       3x          100
kelly        20           gp41        3x          100
```

There could be many persons, with many different dilutions and analytes. The meta info will always be the same down the column. I would like to produce the following data frame:

```
Person     Dilution      Analyte            Meta#1      Meta#2
john        1,2          Blank,mulv,gp41     3x          100
kelly       20           blank,gp41          3x          100
```

I was wondering if anyone knows of any nifty tricks for concatenating information such as this?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.co.il/?ion=1&espv=2&client=ubuntu#q=concatenate+by+group+r)

Comment: @DavidArenburg and @akrun, it's a duplicate, but data.table, dplyr and aggregate are not used in the answers to the other question. One of the answers to the other question uses `plyr`, which has been superseded by other Hadleyverse packages. What do you think is the best course of action when you have a duplicate question, but answers to the original question are outdated or don't include "state of the art" methods: Should I (1) still answer the duplicate question with the new or updated methods, (2) add the new or updated methods as an answer to the original question, (3) both, (4) neither?

Comment: @eipi10 I've closed with a better dupe. But the Whole Google page is full with questions/answers with those packages too

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sounds good, but what do you think about the general issue when the original question doesn't have up-to-date or state-of-the-art answers? (Feel free to move this to chat if you want to discuss.)

Comment: @eipi10 you should close as a dupe in add answer in the target dupe. This way the target will have all the information instead of it being scattered all over the site. This is what I think why SO encourages to close questions as dupes in the first place AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

I changed two of your column names, as `#` is not a legal character in R data frame column names.

#### With the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse=",")))
```

> ```
>   Person Dilution         Analyte Meta1 Meta2
> 1   john      1,2 Blank,mulv,gp41    3x   100
> 2  kelly       20      blank,gp41    3x   100
> ```

#### With the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=",")), by=Person]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Base R` solution would be using `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(.~Person, df, function(x) as.character(unique(x)))


#   Person Dilution         Analyte     Meta1 Meta2
#1   john     1, 2   Blank, mulv, gp41     3x   100
#2  kelly       20       blank, gp41       3x   100
```

Similarly,

```
aggregate(.~Person, df, function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```

Assuming the class of columns with strings are characters and not factors.